# How to get object x or y in nested document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer, I want to get data/object in the nested array.

[show image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSHGW.png)

```js
schedule = await Schedule.findById({_id:'5b496ec3444152122c8d839e'})
console.log(schedule.datalayout.section.data.x)
```

Comment: What does your code look like? And what is it returning currently?

Comment: Image doesn't help but code does for others to help you!

Comment: schedule = await Schedule.findById({_id: '5b496ec3444152122c8d839e'})
console.log(schedule.datalayout.section.data.x);

show in command {"msg":"Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"}

Comment: Don't put the code in the comments, edit and format your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the specified field in the image, you need to determine field index in the array as down below:

```
console.log(schedule.datalayout.section[0].data[0].x)
```

And also, If you want to get all of the x fields in the data array, you need to write something like this:

```
    for(let singleData of schedule.datalayout.section[0].data){
           console.log(singleData.x)
    }
    // for using 'of' keyword, your function must be a async function.
```

Comment: this is just similar to my answer . ^above 
what's the difference?

Comment: can you comment here the result of console.log(schedule.datalayout) ?

Comment: if use for(), i get object x is 0

Comment: No, I mean what is the console.log(schedule.datalayout) full result without using for(). (and also, please note that x value is 0 in the image, too)

Comment: Ok , it is fine up to this level, can you give me the result of console.log(schedule.datalayout.section[0].data) too, please?